# Using panel.mathdensity and panel.densityplot in lattice graphics to plot Bayesian prior and posterior

Tags: r, plot, lattice, bayesian

I am trying to plot a Bayesian prior and posterior distribution using lattice graphics. I would like to have both distributions in one panel, for direct comparison.

I've tried different solutions all day, including `qqmath` but I didn't get them to work. Here's the attempt that has been most successful so far:

```
# my data
d <- dgamma(seq(from=0.00001,to=0.01,by=0.00001),shape = .1, scale = .01)

# my plot
densityplot(~d,
        plot.points=FALSE,
        panel = function(x,...) {
          panel.densityplot(x,...)
          panel.mathdensity(
            dmath = dgamma,
            args = list(shape = .1, scale=.01)
            )
        }
        )
```

Even though the code runs through nicely, it doesn't do what I want it to. It plots the posterior (`d`) but not the prior.

I added `stop("foo")` to `densityplot(...)` to stop execution if an error occurs and I searched online for the error message:

```
Error in eval(substitute(groups), data, environment(formula)) : foo
```

But there are only a few results and they seem unrelated to me.

So, here's my question: Can anyone help me with this approach to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked a similar question which leads to the same result. I got an answer and it was useful. You can find everything [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476744/how-to-plot-bayesian-prior-and-posterior-distributions-in-one-panel-using-r)