# Explanation of plotting Bayesian prior and posterior distributions in one panel using R

Tags: r, plot, statistics, bayesian

Could someone explain with details how this code is working?

```
require(lattice)
?lattice  # essential reading

 data <- dgamma(seq(from=0.00001,to=0.01,by=0.00001),shape = .1, scale = .01)

dfrm <- data.frame(dgam = data, param="s.1.01")
dfrm <- rbind(dfrm, data.frame(dgam =
                                 dgamma( seq(from=0.00001,to=0.01,by=0.00001), 
                                 shape = .2, scale = .01), 
                               param="s.2.01") )
dfrm <- cbind( dfrm, X.val=seq(from=0.00001,to=0.01,by=0.00001) )
str(dfrm)
#'data.frame':  2000 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ dgam : num  5263 2817 1954 1507 1231 ...
# $ param: Factor w/ 2 levels "s.1.01","s.2.01": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# $ X.val: num  1e-05 2e-05 3e-05 4e-05 5e-05 6e-05 7e-05 8e-05 9e-05 1e-04 ...
xyplot( dgam ~ X.val , 
        group=param, 
        data=dfrm, type="l")
```

For instance, In which part is specificating the prior and posterior?

I've found the code in the answer given here [How to plot Bayesian prior and posterior distributions in one panel using R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476744/how-to-plot-bayesian-prior-and-posterior-distributions-in-one-panel-using-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That answer only illustrates how to plot two curves in the same plot, but does not at all involve computing a true posterior given a prior and data.  Namely, it just plots two Gamma distributions with `shape=0.1` and `shape=0.2`, and these are distinguished in the data frame by including a factor column `param` where `"s.1.01"` and `"s.2.01"` indicate the respective distributions.

Comment: BTW, if you are trying to learn Bayesian stats in R, I'd highly recommend [Richard McElreath's "Statistical Rethinking."](http://xcelab.net/rm/statistical-rethinking/)